# Set-theory oriented question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

The [Java Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) uses in its fundamentals a set theory language. In a formal way, a question about set theory relates to mathematics, not programming. But what about the questions which ask for code examples or details of the JMM? Are they on topic here?

Comment: I would say this: If it's about the logic, or mathematics.. Post it to mathSE. If then, you're stuck with the coding when you put it all into practice, then SO will be your friend. You might find that posting it on math.se - People will be able to offer you some coding examples

Comment: @user1326876 I think questions asked for code example are off-topic on MathSE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The study of mathematical models of computation processes is a branch (if not the essence) of computer science. You can ask questions about computer science on **[Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)**.

Questions about programming in Java are off-topic on Computer Science, they belong on Stack Overflow. Questions about the [semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of Java are fully on-topic on Computer Science (and may or may not be ok for Stack Overflow). As a rule of thumb, if you want to include mathematical notation in your question, it's probably off-topic for SO and a good fit for CS.SE. General questions about the JMM are probably a better fit for CS.SE; questions asking for code examples may straddle the border.

If your question is purely about set theory and never mentions Java or other programming topics, it's off-topic for Computer Science, but on-topic on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There is also [Theoretical Computer Science.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) for pure-math questions.

Comment: @user11153 No, [cstheory.se] is not for pure math questions. It is for **research-level** questions about theoretical computer science. If you don't know whether your question might be suitable there, it's not.